# IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

У меня ошибка при заполнении массива *colors*. В этой строчке: `colors[j, 4 * i] = r` и наверное в следующих 3-ех строчках тоже. Эта часть кода выдает следующую ошибку: `IndexError: index 7 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 7`. Можете помочь с этой ошибкой, пожалуйста :)

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

stick_pos = (640, 154)
pos_of_sticks = np.zeros((7, 8))
num_of_iter = 0


img = Image.open('Screenshot_3.png')
listss = []
colors = np.zeros((7, 16))
num = 0
i = 0
j = 0

for i in range(0, 7):
    for j in range(0, 8):
        y = stick_pos[1] - i * 2
        x = stick_pos[0] - j * 3
        num_of_iter += 1
        if num_of_iter == 1:
            pos_of_sticks[i, j] = x
        if num_of_iter == 2:
            pos_of_sticks[i, j] = y
            num_of_iter = 0
print(pos_of_sticks)



for l in np.nditer(pos_of_sticks):
    listss.append(l)
    num += 1
    if num == 2:
        r, g, b, a = img.getpixel(tuple(listss))
        colors[j, 4 * i] = r
        colors[j, 4 * i + 1] = g
        colors[j, 4 * i + 2] = b
        colors[j, 4 * i + 3] = a
        j += 1
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            i = 0
        num = 0
print(colors)
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно не понял зачем для всего использовать numpy массивы.
К тому же, у меня ваша программа ругается на вот эту конструкцию `img.getpixel(tuple(listss))`, что логично, т.к. там получается кортеж numpy массивов.

Посему я бы сделал так:

```
sx, sy = stick_pos = (640, 154)
pos_of_sticks = [(sx - x * 6, sy - y * 2) for y in range(7) for x in range(4)]
print(pos_of_sticks)

img = Image.open('Screenshot_3.png')

colors = np.array(list(map(img.getpixel, pos_of_sticks))).reshape((7, 4*4))
```